# Weblink returned by GraphAPI for shared calendars does not work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office-addins, office365api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We're seeing a similar issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290094/weblink-from-groups-calendarview-ms-graph-api-doesnt-work-event-after-encoding) but with shared calendars.

If we generate a link to a item in our shared calendar the page renders the user's calendar and starts to open the item but hangs once the modal loads.

However, if the user then adds the shared calendar to their OWA client then the links work.

This happens even if the user has added the shared calendar to their Outlook client on their desktop.

We are getting ready to roll this calendar out to our entire organization and we'd rather not have to write up instructions for everyone to have to go through that as a workaround (plus its just janky...).

The URLs we have tried are (note I verified `id` is URL encoded):

- [https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid={id}&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item](https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=%7Bid%7D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item)
- [https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/item/{id}](https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/item/%7Bid%7D)

The browser console has a bunch of errors in it. They all appear to be security related, but we can confirm the user has access. Everything works once the shared calendar has been added to OWA.

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). Source: (()=>{var t={40472... etc..

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). Source: /******/ (function(modules)... etc...

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). Source: (function injectProxy(e... etc...
```

And so forth:

[image]

Comment: Does it work outside of Outlook web add-ins? Have you tried getting the data from a standalone application?

Comment: The link is being rendered in a stand alone web page. We call GraphAPI to get a list of events and render the link to the items.